# Gmail send as with delegates not working (but send as works if logged into main account)

Tags: delegates, smtp, gmail, office365

I have a Gmail account setup that I have multiple delegates that can send/receive emails for the account.  On that account I setup a "Send As" to send email (using SMTP to an office 365 email account).

This was working but I recently removed the old "Send As" and setup a new one (to use Office 365 instead of another service), now the delegates can not send email anymore, they get the below error.

When I log into the gmail account directly I can send email using the "Send As" account no problem.  But if I log in as the delegate to send email, I get the same error.

I tried deleting the delegate and re-adding and it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.  If you need more details please let me know

ERROR:
Message not delivered

You're sending this from a different address or alias using the 'Send mail as' feature. The settings for your 'Send mail as' account are misconfigured or out of date. Check those settings and try resending.

The response from the remote server was:

550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No. I did not..